# Change the JFrames' panel from another JPanel class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

so I got this in my Main class:

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {       
    JFrame Launch = new JFrame();
    Launch.setSize(800, 400);
    Launch.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Launch.setContentPane(new StartView());
    Launch.setTitle("De Hartige Hap");
    Launch.setVisible(true);        
    }
}
```

Now let's say I'm in that Panel ("`StartView()`")

and `onClick` on a button, I want to change the frames' contentpane..

How would I do this?

```
public class StartView extends javax.swing.JPanel {
public StartView() {
    initComponents();
}



private void OrderButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
   /*instead of Launch.setContentPane(new StartView());
    *it has to be (new otherView())
    */
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass your Launch object to your panel object (i.e. new `StartView(launch)`). This way, you can create a method `changeView()` in Launch and you can call this method from your panel (`launch.changeView()`), you can change your view inside that method.

Also, if I may adivce you, take a look at the ModelViewController pattern. This makes sure you keep the View (your panels) and the Controller (your Frame) seperated so you don't get issues like this.

Comment: I've got my MVC in order, at least I think... Basically at the start of the app, it should open a Frame, set sizes, set the pane and open it. Now when I'm inside that panel, I'd like to be able to re-set it to something else. -- I'll give your method a shot.